# how can I bring a React context of lower scope to a React context of higherr scope?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have different context for database and authentication like below.
do not worry about the language context as i do not have a problem with that.

```
root.render(
    <Router>
      <LangContextProvider>
      <DBContextContextProvider>
        <AuthFBContextProvider>
            <App />
        </AuthFBContextProvider>
      </DBContextContextProvider>
      </LangContextProvider>
    </Router>
);
```

the problem here is, I am pulling user data from Firebase which then gets saved to useState
which is shared throughout the App.js but because I have put database context above auth context,
I can't bring anything from auth to db context...

So the question is how can I bring something up from a lower context to a higher context as it is
I have thought about and tried reserving the two levels of context but that gives me another
set of problems which I would like to have as my last resort.

I am able to share data using the App.js but just like using props but I would like to do something direct between the two contexts

thank you

Comment: Maybe not the solution that you are looking for, but why not combine those two providers into one? If that is not what you want, you need to pass state and setter from parent context to child context. Just as same as any parent child component

Comment: I might combine later if things get too complicated... but can you show me how i would pass from child to parent?

Answer (score 0):

To pass props from parent to child context, you would need to restructure your code a little bit:

App.js

```
   const [state, setState] = useState("test")

   return (
      <LangContextProvider value={{state, setState}}>
      <DBContextContextProvider value={{state, setState}}>
        <AuthFBContextProvider value={{state, setState}}>
           <Router>
           //Something here
           </Router>
        </AuthFBContextProvider>
      </DBContextContextProvider>
      </LangContextProvider>)
```

Keep all of your states in app.js, and pass them to the context. Then use setters to adjust values. This way all of your context providers share the same state and can use it.

This is a dumb way to do it, since the point of context is to pass values down to children, not the other way around. The other way is to pass ref to the child component, and use useImperativeHandler. That way you parent can access the child directly and do some things. You can check some docs for that.